# How to add a custom button to allitems view of a custom list

Tags: 2013

How to add a custom button to allitems view of a custom list ?

Its just a list, and with only 1 view, i want to add a custom button on the view, which will navigate user to another page.

Answer (score 1):

View pages are just web part pages.

You can edit the page add a button using a Content Editor Web Part above the list web part.

Edit:

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220045(v=office.15).aspx) may be the way to go. Looks like you can add javascript to the page. With javascript you can render anything.

Edit2:

You can declare a view within a List Definition with the following markup

```
<View BaseViewID="2" 
      Name="8d2719f3-c3c3-415b-989d-33840d8e2ddb" 
      DisplayName="Overridable" 
      Type="HTML" 
      WebPartZoneID="Main" 
      SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" 
      Url="Overridable.aspx"
      DefaultView="TRUE">
  <ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name="Title" />
  </ViewFields>
  <Query />
  <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
  <XslLink>main.xsl</XslLink>
  <JSLink Default="TRUE">~site/Scripts/ButtonRender.js</JSLink>
</View>
```

Notice the `JSLink` attribute at the bottom.

Create the corresponding javascript file.

In the JS, the header template can be customized, which is one option for adding a button.

```
(function () {
    // Initialize the variable that stores the objects.
    var overrideCtx = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates = {};

    overrideCtx.Templates.Header = "<div><button>Test Button</button><br /><#=ctx.ListTitle#>";

    // Set the template to the:
    //  Custom list definition ID
    //  Base view ID
    overrideCtx.BaseViewID = 2;
    overrideCtx.ListTemplateType = 10057;

    // Register the template overrides.
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
})();
```

EDIT3:

The default header can be maintained by using this changing the header definition line to ([Source](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/77262/custom-jslink-rendering-template-how-do-you-get-ajax-paging-working)):

```
overrideCtx.Templates.Header = "<div><button>Test Button</button><br /><#=ctx.ListTitle#>" + RenderTableHeader(overrideCtx) + "</table>";
```

As noted in the linked post, the RenderTableHeader method prints the default table, but doesn't print the table close(Maybe?).

I have not tested this as I don't have a 2013 env in front of me, but this should get you close.

Comment: thank you, but I want to do it in visual studio with list defintion

Comment: Please add more details to your answer to make it less dependent in the links. E.g. outline the steps needed

Comment: datasheet view is not visible anymore pleazo pleazo helpo

Comment: I assume you mean the edit button is gone (as well as the rest of the header?)

Comment: Just wondering. It isn't easier to use a module instead?

Comment: For what part? It might be, if you have a better idea please add it as a new answer.